# Wait for threads in threadpool between loop iterations

Tags: c, loops, gcc, threadpool, wait

I have a few programs doing a bunch of calculations, and since my new computer has a multicore processor I decided to rewrite my programs for multithreading. I found Johan Hanssen Seferidis' [thpool library](https://github.com/Pithikos/C-Thread-Pool) and am trying to work with it.

I have a small loop (say `0 < j < 12`) embedded in a larger loop (`0 < i < 40000`). For each iteration of `i` the small j-loop gives out its work to a threadpool.  There is one piece of work for each j.  The threads come up and grab anything that hasn't been taken. I need a way for the large i-loop to wait until all threads have finished their work in the j-loop, and any I/O operations too, and then proceed with i++.

Simple example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "thpool.h"

int i;

void task1(int a){
printf("# Thread working: %u\n", (int)pthread_self());
printf(" Task 1 running..\n");
printf("%d\n", 10*i+a);
}

int main(){
int j;

#define NUM_HANDLER_THREADS 3

thpool_t* threadpool;
threadpool=thpool_init(NUM_HANDLER_THREADS);

for (i=0; i<5; i++)
  for (j=0; j<10; j++) {
    thpool_add_work(threadpool, (void*)task1, (void*)j);
    };

sleep(2);
puts("Will kill threadpool");
thpool_destroy(threadpool);

return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```
gcc main.c thpool.c -pthread -o test
```

Executing the above should (i.e. what I would like) write five blocks 0-9, 10-19, ..., 40-49 in that order, but the elements of each block may be in more or less random order. Instead, the program goes through the whole i-loop too fast, so by the time the threads start to write i==5 already, so I get 50-59 five times, in random order.

I hope I am clear on what I am trying to do. Maybe something like this:

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
  for (j=0; j<10; j++) {
  thpool_add_work(threadpool, (void*)task1, (void*)j);
  wait_for_all_threads_to_finish();
  }
};
```

Any ideas? Joining? Exiting? Semaphores? This is all new to me, so thank you for your patience.

Comment: You are just having a data race. Multiple threads access the same variable `i` without locks. Rather than adding synchronization, just don't access it. Pass all needed information to the workers via function parameters.

Comment: If you want your work done in blocks of N rather than in a contiguous stream, you do need synchronization. It is not evident why such blocks are needed though.

Comment: Hi, I am the guy who made the C-Thread-Pool library. As of January 2015 there is the function `thpool_wait()` that can do exactly what you want. Notice that the API has changed slightly (for the better).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use semaphores like this:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <semaphore.h>
    #include "thpool.h"

    int i;
    sem_t sem;

    void
    task1(int a)
    {
      sem_post(&sem);
      printf("# Thread working: %u\n", (int)pthread_self());
      printf(" Task 1 running..\n");
      printf("%d\n", 10*i+a);
    }

    int
    main(void)
    {
      int j;

      if (sem_init(&sem, 0, 0) == -1)
        abort();

      #define NUM_HANDLER_THREADS 3

      thpool_t* threadpool;
      threadpool=thpool_init(NUM_HANDLER_THREADS);

      for (i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
          for (j=0; j<10; j++)
            {
              thpool_add_work(threadpool, (void*)task1, (void*)j);
              sem_wait(&sem);
            }
        }

      sleep(2);
      puts("Will kill threadpool");
      thpool_destroy(threadpool);

      return 0;
    }
```

Also try experiment with:

```
    void
    task1(int a)
    {
      printf("# Thread working: %u\n", (int)pthread_self());
      printf(" Task 1 running..\n");
      printf("%d\n", 10*i+a);
      sem_post(&sem);
    }
```

And look at the difference. Good luck.

Comment: I tried what you suggested and it doesn't do what I would like. By putting `sem_wait(&sem);` _inside_ the j-loop everything is executed as if I wasn't even using multithreading: Nothing happens until the next time `j` is incremented. What I need is something like this: For each new value of `i` the j-loop spins andsends work to the threadpool. The order in which each `j` is done is not important, what is important is that **all** `j`'s are finished calculating before `i` can be incremented. I tried moving the `sem_wait(&sem);` to outside of the j-loop, but still inside the i-loop, but no go:(